Nondecreasing interval on a locally absolutely continuous function $f: [a, b] \to \mathbb{R}$ with $f(b) > f(a)$
For my research, I need to verify whether a function $f: [a, b] \to \mathbb{R}$ with $f(b) > f(a)$
has a nondecreasing interval $(c, d) \subset [a, b]$ such that $f$ is increasing on that interval and $f(c) \geq f(x)$ for all $x \in [a, c]$. Here is an example where two of the intervals I'm looking for are highlitghted in green:

I can impose "nice" properties to my function if needed. It seems reasonable that at least absolute continuity is required, to discart functions like the Cantor function.
The statement makes sense to me, and I am almost sure it is true. There are strange functions, like $f(x) = x \sin(\frac{1}{x}) + x$, which cross $0$ at $x = 0$, but you cannot say that there is a neighborhood of $0$ where $f$ is nondecreasing. However, I am not looking for a neighborhood of any particular point.
There might be an simple solution to this, but I am fairly new to this concepts, and I have been stuck for a couple of days.
Thank you in advance.

This isn't true.
It is well-known that there is a Borel set $B \subset [0,1]$ with the property that $|I \cap B| > 0$ and $|I \setminus B| > 0$ for every nontrivial interval $I \subset [0,1]$. Swapping $B$ with $[0,1] \setminus B$ if necessary you can assume that $|B| \ge |[0,1] \setminus B|$.
Define
$$f(x) = \int_0^x \chi_B(t) - \chi_{[0,1]\setminus B}(t) \, dt.$$ Then $f :[0,1] \to \mathbf R$ is absolutely continuous, $f(0) = 0$, and $f(1) = |B| - |[0,1] \setminus B| \ge 0$. The theory of AC functions tells you that $f$ is differentiable almost everywhere and that
$$f'(x) = \chi_B(x) - \chi_{[0,1]\setminus B}(x)$$ for almost every $x \in [0,1]$. Thus $f'$ assumes the value  $-1$ on a set of positive measure in every nontrivial interval $I \subset [0,1]$.
If $f$ were nondecreasing on some interval $I$ it would follow that $f' \ge 0$ almost everywhere in that interval, contrary to construction.
Of course, this example only has $f(0) \le f(1)$. For strict inequality you could consider for example $f(x) + \dfrac x2$.
